# Access to Windows data though Windows Handles

Tags: windows, winapi, handle

I am programming in Win32 with FPC IDE
I create Windows objects (like Windows, Pen, Brush, etc) and Windows returns me Handles. I want to directly access to the objects' data though those Handles. 
Is it possible ? If yes, how?

Comment: `HANDLE`s are basically pointers, so memory addresses. If you know the internal representation of such an `object`, of course it's possible, but I don't see any reason to do so, since all the operations should be performed by WinAPIs (that take `HANDLE`s as arguments).

Comment: @Cristi: `HANDLE`s are not pointers. They are indexes into kernel-controlled containers. Even if they were pointers, and you did know the internal representation, you wouldn't be able to access protected kernel memory. `HWND`s, on the other hand, are obfuscated pointers to kernel-controlled structures, that are mapped read-only into user mode memory.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you friends, but for example : how can I change color of a pen object without creating new pen ? >>>

Comment: Thank you, @IInspectable, for deeper information provided.

Comment: @TạĐặngVĩnhPhúc: you can use `SetDCPenColor()` to change the pen color of an `HDC` that has a stock `DC_PEN` selected into it, but you cannot change the color of an `HPEN` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to directly access to the objects' data though those handles. Is it possible?

No. These handles are opaque. Interact with these objects using the API provided.

Comment: thank you, I see. So every time I wanna change color of a selected pen (of a DC), i MUST creating new one ?

Comment: Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162970(v=vs.85).aspx) help?

Answer (score 1):

The *correct* way to access the data of a graphic object, such as a pen or brush, is to use [`GetObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904.aspx). But if you want to *modify* such an object, you need to create a new object using the appropriate API ([`CreatePenIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183510.aspx), etc), unless there is an API specifically for manipulating an existing object (such as [`SetDCPenColor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162970.aspx) when the stock `DC_PEN` is selected into an `HDC`).

Comment: `SetDCPenColor` doesn't really manipulate a GDI object. It merely stores a `COLORREF` value that is used for drawing, when the `DC_PEN` is selected into a device context.

Comment: Thank you... so every time i want to use different styles, colors, region of pen, brush, region, i have to creating new one?

Comment: @TạĐặngVĩnhPhúc: Yes.  You can create them as needed per drawing, or you can create them beforehand and reuse them for multiple drawings.